# Replacing items in JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am new to javascript. I am trying to replace a JSON elements with a set values passed from another function. When i parse the object I am getting an error message  unexpected token at pos 0.

Thank you.

```
var defaultMessage = {
    "MTI": "1101",
    dataElements: {
        "DE01": "101",
        "DE02": "201",
        "DE03": "301",
        "DE04": "401",
        "DE05": "501",
        "DE06": "601",
        "DE07": "701"
    }
}


replaceDefaultElements: (testElements) => {
    console.info(testElements)
    console.info(defaultMessage);
    var messageElements = JSON.parse(defaultMessage.dataElements);
    Object.keys(testElements).forEach(function (key) {
        messageElements[key] = testElements[key];
    });
    return messageElements;
}

//Calling from JEST test function:

test('Should be ', () => {
    expect(functions.replaceDefaultElements('{"MTI":"1101",{"DE01":"XXX"}}')).toEqual({
        "MTI": "1101",
        dataElements: {
            "DE01": "XXX",
            "DE02": "201",
            "DE03": "301",
            "DE04": "401",
            "DE05": "501",
            "DE06": "601",
            "DE07": "701"
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i parse the object I am getting an error message unexpected token at pos 0.

`defaultMessage.dataElements` is a *JavaScript* object. [It isn't JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Don't use `JSON.parse` there.

`testElements`, on the other hand, **is** JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `JSON.parse(defaultMessage.dataElements)` with  `defaultMessage.dataElements`

Replace `Object.keys(testElements)` with `Object.keys(JSON.parse(testElements))`

Hope it will work